# apache2 installation conflicts with previous lampp content

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server

hej,

i downloaded xampp-linux-1.7.3a.tar.gz and installed it manually, not with aptitude. That was a mistake as proved later, due to some configurational issues i decided to remove it and install it via aptitude install apache2.
Now the previous lampp conflicts with the new apache2, i get this error message.

> - Starting web server apache2
>     apache2: Could not reliably determine
>     the server's fully qualified domain
>     name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
>     (98)Address already in use: make_sock:
>     could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
>     no listening sockets available,
>     shutting down

how can delete the existing lampp files entirely or how can i configure apache2 to work as intended ?

any help will be appreciated

Comment: looks like you have more than one port 80 instance running

Answer (score 1):

All files for xampp are in one central location, `/opt/lampp`.

Simply run:

```
/opt/lampp/lampp stop
```

to stop the Apache, SQL and PHP services, then:

```
rm -rf /opt/lampp
```

to remove the content.

You can then start up your apache2 installation via `apache2ctl start`. You'll want to modify the `ServerName` directive in `httpd.conf` to get rid of the annoying hostname error as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have skype running then that could stop port 80 from running. Go to to your skype preferences and make sure that it doesn't use port 80 from the advanced section in the settings.

Also you can try and change the port that apache uses to avoid any conflicts?